# Does catnip repel rats, mice and cockroaches?

Tags: plants, pesticides

[Cat-world](http://www.cat-world.com.au/all-about-catnip) claims that catnip can repel rats, mice and cockroaches.

> It was also discovered that catnip repels cockroaches too!

and

> Rats & mice are also believed to have a strong dislike of catnip & will avoid places where it grows.

Is it true?

Comment: Does attracting a predator count as repelling prey? :p